# Encode AAC file from stream

Tags: c#, naudio, aac

I would like to be able to save an AAC audio file from a stream (over WCF) with C#.
NAudio currently only allows reading AAC files and not streams, anyway to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now (as of NAudio 1.7), the best way is to save a WAV and then convert to AAC.  If your version of Windows has an AAC Media Foundation encoder, then you can use NAudio's MediaFoundationEncoder class to do this.

If you want stream support, one way is to use [NAudio.SharpMediaFoundation](https://github.com/markheath/NAudio.SharpMediaFoundation), which makes use of SharpDX to allow encoding to streams.

Comment: Mark, the whole issue is that passing a WAV recording is bad for us since the size of the file is too large. We want to be able to save an AAC or some other Apple enabled sound format and have our web service receive it on server side.

Comment: One approach you may be able to take is find a command line AAC encoder that allows you to pass the PCM into the stdin. I've had good results doing this with lame.exe for making MP3 files.

Comment: command line encoders are quit unhandy. You can use CSCore in combination with NAudio (CSCore supports streams).

Comment: To expand on @FlorianR. you can do the following with CSCore:
`using (var decoder = new MediaFoundationDecoder(inStream)) {
    using (var encoder = MediaFoundationEncoder.CreateAACEncoder(decoder.WaveFormat, outStream)) {
        MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeWholeSource(encoder, decoder);    }
}`